# Sum column values and also check null condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this column converted to money and on top of this I need sum this column values and need to set a validation like if the column has null values it has to return zero.

```
select '$ '+ CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,0),CONVERT(money, Amt_Value)),1) as  [Amount]  from Products
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM and ISNULL

```
select '$ '+ CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(decimal(10,0),CONVERT(money, ISNULL(SUM(Amt_Value),0.00))),1) as  [Amount]  from Products
```